# Stuck at 'Uploading Application' using vmc push/update

Tags: lift, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to upload a lift webapp to CF but keep getting stuck at 'Uploading Application'. I've tried from two different machines, on two different networks, on two different operating systems. The application creates in a STOPPED state but the war file never gets uploaded.

I've also tried deleting the application and re-pushing, to no avail. Here's a sample trace output. Nothing else is printed after 'Uploading Application:'

```
          "detection": [
        {
          "*.war": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
<<<
>>>
REQUEST: get http://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps/cps-test-harness
RESPONSE_HEADERS:
    server : nginx
    date : Fri, 01 Jun 2012 09:44:34 GMT
    content_type : application/json; charset=utf-8
    transfer_encoding : chunked
    connection : keep-alive
    keep_alive : timeout=20
    etag : "01c08aca6ec2d2e0ca88b2bb0ed69d97"
    cache_control : max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
    x_ua_compatible : IE=Edge,chrome=1
    x_vcap_backend : 172.30.49.4:9022
    x_vcap_router : 172.30.49.23
RESPONSE: [200]
{
  "name": "cps-test-harness",
  "staging": {
    "model": "lift",
    "stack": "java"
  },
  "uris": [
    "cps-test-harness.cloudfoundry.com"
  ],
  "instances": 1,
  "runningInstances": 0,
  "resources": {
    "memory": 512,
    "disk": 2048,
    "fds": 256
  },
  "state": "STOPPED",
  "services": [
    "postgresql-64fb1"
  ],
  "version": "6b388f21b6b27a0a0d0f71defc77a6c6-0",
  "env": [

  ],
  "meta": {
    "debug": null,
    "console": null,
    "version": 2,
    "created": 1338543874
  }
}
<<<
Uploading Application:
```

Comment: Can you link to the source of your app so I can try and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Gareth, just checking if you resolved this?

Comment: Hi Glenn - I gave up and used Heroku; maybe I'll try again sometime.

Comment: Actually you just prompted me to have another go.. it doesn't get stuck any more so I guess it was just a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 2):

To close this question out, the original poster found a resolution in the comments above:

> Actually you just prompted me to have another go.. it doesn't get stuck any more so I guess it was just a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a CF installation. The restarting of CF services( /bin/vcap restart ) solved the deployment issue and the vmc apps indicates the application as running.